# C#: How to find and create instances which fulfills multiple type constraints

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, activator, type-constraints

Say I have a generic method with multiple type constraints, this this:

```
public static void DoSomethingAwesome<T>(T thing)
    where T : IThing, IAwesome, IComparable<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Now.... how can I, using reflection, create something I can send in there?

If it was only one constraint I know I can do it like this:

```
var types = assembly
      .GetTypes()
      .Where(typeof (IThing).IsAssignableFrom)

foreach(var t in types)
    DoSomethingAwesome((IThing) Activator.CreateInstance(t));
```

But, can't really cast to multiple interfaces... how on earth can I solve this? You could say I am pretty much lost here now :P

*Title got kind of long and complex as I wasn't sure what to call this, please improve if you can*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to Reed and Loren's answers about finding suitable types, note that you still won't be able to call DoSomethingAwesome by casting, because as you have found, the compiler doesn't provide a way to cast the instantiated object to multiple interfaces.  You have two options:

1. Create a new interface
   IAwesomeComparableThing which
   derives from IThing, IAwesome and
   IComparable<T>, have your
   types implement that, and cast to
   that.
2. Invoke DoSomethingAwesome through
   reflection.  To do this, you will
   need to get the MethodInfo for the
   DoSomethingAwesome generic method,
   then call
   MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod with
   your type that implements all three
   interfaces.

Example of (2):

```
Type type = sometype; // For example found using reeds method
MethodInfo mgeneric = typeof(Awesomeiser).GetMethod("DoSomethingAwesome");
MethodInfo mspecific = mgeneric.MakeGenericMethod(new [] { type });
mspecific.Invoke(null, new [] { type });
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to replicate Reed and Loren's answers about how to locate suitable types.  I am assuming that, using the other answers, you can locate a suitable type and instantiate an instance (using Activator.CreateInstance).  You then pass this type to MakeGenericMethod, and the instance to Invoke.  Sorry for lack of clarity.

Comment: Aah, think I got it now. But wat is m? should it be mgeneric?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's some reason you can't do

```
var types = assembly
.GetTypes()
.Where(typeof (IThing).IsAssignableFrom && typeof (IAwesome).IsAssignableFrom))
```

Comment: Doesn't handle the IComparable<T> constraint, though, which is the trickiest.

Comment: To instantiate them, use Activator.CreateInstance as you do in the question.  Then you have the separate problem of passing them to the method; I've posted an answer that discusses this.

Comment: Well, I can, and will, of course do that, but that will just *find* those classes. I will still have trouble instantiating them.

Comment: Could you say what kind of trouble you are having instantiating them?  As you know, Activator.CreateInstance should do that for you; if it isn't, what's the error you're seeing?  Or is the problem in *casting* the created instance to a type that the compiler will let you pass to the generic method?  If so see my answer for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need a type that's assignable from all of your constraints.  The first two are easy, but the third is a bit trickier:

```
// Using
static bool IsIComparable(Type thing)
    {
        foreach (Type interfaceType in thing.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (interfaceType.IsGenericType && interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IComparable<>))
            {
                Type[] arguments = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments();
                if (arguments.Length == 1)
                {
                    if (arguments[0] == thing)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


// This returns an enumerable of compatible types:
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where( t => 
   typeof(IThing).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
   typeof(IAwesome).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
   IsIComparable(t) );
```

Comment: This, as far as I can see, also just help me find those types. Not instantiating them in a way I can send them into a generic method. The `IsComparable` method looks very helpful though, so thank you for that one :)